# Import pandas on jupyter ipython notebook fails

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

I am able to import the pandas package within the spyder ide; however, if I attempt to open a new juypter notebook, the import fails.

I use the Anaconda package distribution on MAC OS X.

Here is what I do:

```
In [1]: import pandas
```

and this is the response I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-97925edf8fb0> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     11                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     12                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
---> 13                       "extensions first.".format(module))
     14 
     15 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Comment: Have you tried `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` as stated in the error message?

Comment: If @albert 's suggestion doesn't work you could get a proper python setup by using brew. For instance, you could follow the first three steps of this guide: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x

Comment: @albert where exactly should I paste "python setup.py build_ext --inplace"?

Comment: @Pat in your system teminal. You should make sure that you're in the directory that contains Pandas' setup.py

Comment: The terminal returns: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 12):

You have more than one Python 2 engines installed. One in your main OS platform, another one inside Anaconda's virtual environment. You need to install Panda on the latter.

Run in your Bash prompt:

```
which python
```

Then run the following in Jupyter/IPython and compare the result with the output you got from the Bash script:

```
from sys import executable
print(executable)
```

If they differ, you should note the result of the latter (i.e. copy it), and then go to your Bash prompt, and do as follows:

```
<the 2nd output> -m pip install pandas
```

so it would be something **like** this:

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/python2 -m pip install pandas
```

And Pandas will be installed for your Anaconda Python.

There is a way to add library paths to your existing environment, using `sys.path.append('path to alternative locations')`, but this has to be done every time your want to use the alternative environment as the effects are temporary.

You can alternatively install everything in your main environment:

```
python -m pip install cython scipy panda matplotlib jupyter notebook ipython
```

## Update:

Based on responses to the above section:

Install `homebrew` like so:

In your Terminal:

```
xcode-select --install

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then run:

```
brew doctor
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Now go ahead and install Python 2 through Brew:

```
brew install python
```

or for Python 3

```
brew install python3
```

Or do both. The install other useful stuff!

```
brew install git conda gfortran clang pkg-config
```

Then you can go ahead and install your desired libraries either using brew, or using `pip`, but first you should ensure that `pip` itself is installed.

```
easy_install pip
```

then you can install Python packages like so (NumPy is included in SciPy, and SciPy and Matplotlib depend on Cython and C, Scipy additionally uses fortran for ODE):

```
python2 -m install cython scipy pandas matplotlib jupyter
```

you can do that same thing for Python 3.

This clean install should really solve the problem. If it didn't, download Python from Python.org and re-install it. `brew` sometime refuses to install a package if it finds out that the package already exists. I don't recommend removing Python 2 so that you can install it through `brew`. That might cause issues with OS X. So the best alternative is to repair existing installations by installing the package downloaded from the website. OS X ensures that the package is installed in the right place. Once this is done, you can then go back to the instructions, but start from `brew install python3`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on Mac OS X with Anaconda (Python 2). I tried importing the pandas package in python repl, and got this error:

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Therefore, I've added the following lines to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And this has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Same issue. Python 2 on mac. Used above mentioned exports and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do it is install the libraries straight in Jupyter, you can try, in the cell:

```
!pip install pandas
```

or

```
!pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: Or `%pip install pandas` for modern set-ups. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190436/8508004), [here](https://twitter.com/python_tip/status/1167426141080182784), or [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11524) for more about it.