# Installing a pip package from within a Jupyter Notebook not working

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When I run `!pip install geocoder` in Jupyter Notebook I get the same output as running `pip install geocoder` in the terminal but the geocoder package is not available when I try to import it.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Anaconda 4.0.0 and pip 8.1.2

**Installing geocoder:**

```
!pip install geocoder

The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting geocoder
  Downloading geocoder-1.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (195kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 3.2MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from geocoder)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ratelim in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from geocoder)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from geocoder)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): click in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from geocoder)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decorator-4.0.10-py2.7.egg (from ratelim->geocoder)
Installing collected packages: geocoder
Successfully installed geocoder-1.15.1
```

**Then try to import it:**

```
import geocoder

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-603a981d39f2> in <module>()
----> 1 import geocoder

ImportError: No module named geocoder
```

I also tried shutting down the notebook and restarting it without any luck.

**Edit:** I found that using the terminal installs the geocoder package in `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and using a notebook installs it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` which is not in the path. `sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')` solves the problem for the current session.

So how can I permanently modify the path or tell pip where to install geocoder?

Comment: Those are Python 2 packages. Is your notebook using a Python 2 kernel or a Python 3 kernel?

Comment: Its using Python 2

Comment: [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Check jupyter notebook configuration at C:\Users\<username>\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695158/python-2-7-cannot-import-geocoder-library

Answer (score 150):

In IPython 7.3 and later, there is a magic [`%pip`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip) and [`%conda`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-conda) command that will run in the current kernel.

```
%pip install geocoder
```

In earlier versions, you need to use sys to fix the problem like in [the answer by FlyingZebra1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473278/309334)

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install geocoder
```

Comment: Indeed a good solution. Does "install in current kernel" mean that package installed through this method will be available to use while the kernel is running. When it is stopped and run the next time, install command has to be executed again? Correct?

Comment: How we can create other kernal di Jupyter Notebook? Is a kernel in Jupyter Notebook actually the same as environment in Python?

Comment: @Veki The package manager will *run* in the current kernel, but *install* in the current **environment**, i.e. the package will be saved to disk. I just edited to clarify. Maybe Eponymous misunderstood the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip): *"Run the [ ] package manager within the current kernel."*

Answer (score 89):

```
! pip install --user <package>
```

The `!` tells the notebook to execute the cell as a shell command.

Comment: Question itself mentions use of '!', as per my understanding initially the question was asked to find out why geocoder module is not working even after successful installation.

Comment: This doesn't always work, because sometimes the `pip` that's called with a shell command is not actually the installer for the python version in your virtualenv. Using `%pip` magic instead of `!pip` (shell command) is the way to go, as in the answer by @eponymous .

Answer (score 44):

```
%pip install geocoder
```

in 2019.

In older versions of conda:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install geocoder
```

Comment: "older versions of conda"? What does `conda` have to do with this? Maybe you're confusing it with Anaconda? It's actually IPython that provides the magic command, but I guess specific versions of the Anaconda Distribution are tied to specific versions of IPython.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `pyarrow` is saved by `pip` into `dist-packages` (in your case `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`). This path is skipped by Jupyter so `pip` won't help.

As a solution I suggest adding in the first block

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

or whatever is path or python version. In case of Python 3.5 this is

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages")
```

Comment: Sorry, what does `pyarrow` have to do with this? I'm guessing that's the module that you had a problem with, but OP is trying to install `geocoder`, so I guess you just forgot to swap out "`pyarrow`" for "`geocoder`", or more generally, "the package".

Comment: @wjandrea good question. It's been 5.5 years - no idea. I would advise using more current answers. Hopefully the OP isn't using Ubuntu14.04 nor Python2.7 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In jupyter notebook under python 3.6, the following line works:

```
!source activate py36;pip install <...>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Jupyter nOtebook /Mac Platform /Python 3 :

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [FlyingZebra1's answer](/a/50473278/4518341) but the specific code is not relevant to the question. Please don't post duplicate answers. Check out [answer] for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some shell magic: %%sh 
`%%sh pip install geocoder`
let me know if it works, thanks

Comment: This did not work for me. Looks like it is a different python environment based on my experience on SageMaker.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
```

```
source activate py27
```

```
pip install geocoder
```

Comment: This looks like a working solution, but it seriously needs a description. It looks like the first command is just to create an example environment, then you activate the environment **from Bash** and run `pip` from there instead of via `!pip` in IPython. Then if you launch IPython, you'll be able to import `geocoder`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option : 
you can also create a bash cell in jupyter using bash kernel and then `pip install geocoder`. That should work

Comment: Isn't that essentially what `!` does?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I found these instructions that worked for me.

```
# Example of installing handcalcs directly from a notebook
!pip install --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed handcalcs
```

ref: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

> Issues may arise when using pip and conda together. When combining
> conda and pip, it is best to use an isolated conda environment. Only
> after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible
> should pip be used to install any remaining software. If modifications
> are needed to the environment, it is best to create a new environment
> rather than running conda after pip. When appropriate, conda and pip
> requirements should be stored in text files.
>
> We recommend that you:
>
> Use pip only after conda
>
> Install as many requirements as possible with conda then use pip.
>
> Pip should be run with --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed (the default).
>
> Do not use pip with the --user argument, avoid all users installs.

Comment: *"Pip should be run with `--upgrade-strategy only-if-needed` (**the default**)."* - If that option is the default then it sounds like a red herring. Or maybe you were using an older version of pip where it wasn't the default or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* start pip with an exclamation point. There's no guarantee that it'll use the python from your running kernel.

Nowadays you can just run `pip` or `conda` without any signal:

```
pip install pandas
```

Since [automagic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-automagic) is now the default, Jupyter will automatically call [`%pip`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip) and use the correct pip for your kernel.

Remember that it's always better to have your dependencies in an external file called `requirements.txt` and fix their version number. Than you can just run in your first cell:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

Using pip2 worked for me:

```
!pip2 install geocoder
...
import geocoder
g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')
g.latlng
[37.3860517, -122.0838511]
```