# python 2.7 cannot import geocoder library

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, geocoding

Python 2.7.10 on win32. windows 8.1

used pip to install geocoder library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder/1.8.0

get this error when I try and import the library

```
>>> import geocoder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\geocoder\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from geocoder.api import get, yahoo, bing, geonames, mapquest, google, mapbox  # noqa
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\geocoder\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from geocoder.freegeoip import FreeGeoIP
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\geocoder\freegeoip.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ratelim
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\ratelim\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
ImportError: No module named decorator
>>>
```

I thought just an install of the decorator library would fix the situtation but that library was already installed

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts>pip install decorator
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\python27\arcgis10.4\lib\site-packages
```

**update**

```
C:\Users\rizagha>python --version
Python 2.7.10

C:\Users\rizagha>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from decorator import decorator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named decorator
```

something that may be complicating this is I have python 32 bit and 64 bit installed via arcgis...

Comment: on your command line type python --version, if it's 2.7 then enter the python interpreter and try manually type from decorator import decorator

Comment: hmm so check my edit, that module didnt import..

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](/q/14295680/4518341) but I can't remember if Python 2 has any specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following command to install the module

```
[root@server] python -m pip install decorator
```

This should install the module to the python library of the interpreter that starts when you run the python command

then try start up your interpreter again and try to import the module (assuming it doesn't say it's already satisfied)

```
[root@server] python
>> from decorator import decorator
>>
```

if it does say that it's already satisfied, then you can try to uninstall it using pip and then reinstall it by explicitly specifying the python -m command

```
[root@server] pip uninstall decorator
[root@server] python -m pip install decorator
```

then you can check to see if the module is available in your default interpretor

```
[root@server] python
>> from decorator import decorator
>>
```

Comment: nope did not work, says requirement already satisfied for decorator, but when I import the module it says it is not there

Comment: try and do a pip uninstall (without explicitly typing python -m) and then try to reinstall it using python -m pip install decorator

Comment: awesome that worked! rewrite your answer so I can except it!