# ModuleNotFoundError in jupyter notebook when importing a module after conda install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to use conda to set up one of my projects. I installed openCV by `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`. When I run `conda list`, I can see openCV in the list. Running `python -i` and then `import cv2` works, but when I open up Jupyter Notebook and navigate to that folder (I have to do it this way because running `jupyter notebook` in the directory also pulls up an error), and open up a notebook which imports cv2, I get an error. Why is this happening, and how would I solve it? Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said before, I wasn't able to start Jupyter Notebook from the command line, I had to start it from the start menu and navigate to my folder. Because of that, my notebook wasn't working in the conda environment that I created. I fixed that by running `python -m ipykernal install --user --name <env_name> --display-name "<display_name>"`. I had to `conda install ipykernel`. It works now. Thanks for the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that indicates that the notebook is running with a different Python or in a different environment from Python in the command prompt. Check sys.executable to see which Python it's running in, and sys.path to see where it's looking for imports

Comment: I added the output of `sys.executable` and `path` to my question when I ran those from the command line using `python -i` after activating the environment and when I ran those from the notebook. I get different outputs. Might that be what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Everybody says that pip installing from notebook is not the best practice, but maybe for a fast try it would do the thing:

```
# Install a conda package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} packagename

# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install packagename
```

I used it from [Install python packages on Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801963/install-python-packages-on-jupyter-notebook) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Activate environment before running**
`conda activate <environment-name>`

**Step 2: Install ipykernel**
`conda install -c anaconda ipykernel`

**Step 3: Add the conda environment to ipykernel**
`ipython kernel install --name <environment-name> --user`

**Step 4: Install your package**
`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

**References:**
[How to add your Conda environment to your jupyter notebook in just 4 steps](https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084)

[Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)