# Cannot install scikit-surprise on my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, recommendation-engine

[image]

I am building a recommendation engine and am not able to install surprise, i thought the problem was because i didn't have a c compiler(since i found some people saying it would solve the problem) so i installed it too but couldn't solve anything. i even tried runing the pip install on my command prompt and it gave an error.

Comment: You forgot the `!` before `pip`. So, the command should be `!pip install scikit-surprise`

Comment: you should use `!pip instal ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing a pip package from within a Jupyter Notebook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some users have suggested that i use '!' before pip but `pip install` works fine for me all the time as u see in the picture for numpy.

the solution i found for this was

Step 1 : Go to anaconda command prompt

Step 2 : Type conda update --all

Step 3 : Type `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise`

i hope this is helpful to anyone who encounters this error in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, change your enviroment interpreter to python <= 3.7 version

scikit-surprise it´s not support for greater version of python.

For more information see also https://pypi.org/project/scikit-surprise/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for me as to first update all my conda packages and then install scikit-surprise. You can follow the steps as well if it works out for you:

1. Go to anaconda command prompt
2. Type conda update --all
3. Type conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise

Also I'm running python 3.8.8.

Answer (score 1):

The key error is in Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. You have to download supporting build tools for C++(sometimes just downloading it from MS website wont work), if you are using visual studio 2022 for python development, you have to modify your installer and download missing build tools, I think its titled "Desktop Development with C++ (not just python developer/IDE) and check almost all tools", however it consumes bit of system space, however it sorted this problem of installing many packages in python which was not working otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it on python 3.7 after installing **python3.7-dev**

I found the solution in this link https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/issues/283#issuecomment-515878185

Answer (score 0):

Try this in shell:    `pip install scikit-surprise==1.0.4`

Comment: Your answer can be improved by adding other supporting material. This looks more like a comment right now.

Comment: Where are you suggesting they run that @Joerude? On command line/terminal or in a cell inside the notebook? If the latter, that is working behind the scenes with the magics `%pip install <package_name>` because auto-magics is usually on by default. See more about the modern `%pip install` and `%conda install` magics [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Short-version, PRO-TIP: Avoid using an exclamation with `pip` & `conda` these days & use the magic command that insures installation to correct environment.