# How do I install researchpy on Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install `researchpy` with `pip install researchpy` or `pip3 install researchpy` on Jupyter but it gives the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'researchpy'
```

Could you help me to install it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing a pip package from within a Jupyter Notebook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the command below from the terminal(like cmd.exe):

```
pip install researchpy
```

Comment: I did but inspite of this i couldn't install researchpy..

Comment: Try: pip install researchpy --user

Comment: Run this command in your anaconda prompt terminal. Then try loading in jupyter notebook.