# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, seaborn, jupyter, conda

I keep getting the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
when trying to import seaborn.
[image]

I have installed seaborn using both pip install seaborn and conda install seaborn. [image]

I saw on seaborn that I am not the only one who has had this issue, but I have not been able to resolve this problem, how can I check and updated that my pip/conda points to the same installation as my interpreter?[image]

**EDIT**:
I have tried running !pip install seaborn in the notebook, but this still does not work. I have also created my own conda env and installed seaborn (it shows base in the photos) but this also did not work.[image]

Comment: You installed seaborn to the (base) environment in conda. Are you running your jupyter notebook from the same environment?

Comment: Can you try running `!pip install seaborn` from your jupyter cell and then try importing?

Comment: a more robust way is to use [line magic %pip (SO explanation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190436/10413145) to directly install the package with the kernel you are using

Comment: Can you run `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` inside your jupyter notebook? Does it return `/opt/miniconda3/bin/python`?

Comment: running print(sys.executable) does in fact point to the wrong path, it points to:

        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6

instead of
        /opt/miniconda3/bin/python

Answer (score 6):

you might have an old version of Jupyter notebook, so need to try this command to install it in the current kernel.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install seaborn
```

In the New Jupyter version (2019) can be installed simply as:

```
%pip install seaborn
```

Note: Answer from different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working/56190436#56190436)!

Answer (score 0):

Finally it got solved, and below command worked for me

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade seaborn
```

A lot of suggestions tried, but when i came across upgrading my pip, and suggested command on terminal was below. I updated my install command like above and it works.

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: `%pip install seaborn` run inside a cell of your running notebook should have been equivalent to that. However, maybe you had really outdated components involved. If you do update, you should be able to use the magic install commands to install to the correct environment going forward. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added in 2019 to be more convenient than your command and to be better than the outdated use in conjunction with the exclamation point.

Comment: <continued> After use of the magic install commands, you always need to restart the kernel to insure the changes take effect. For particularly complex installs, such as ipywidgets, it is best to restart Jupyter and your browser entirely.