# import cassandra module from Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, cassandra, jupyter-notebook

I execute pip install `cassandra-driver` successfully
and when I type

`python -c 'import cassandra; print (cassandra.__version__)'` I got `3.24.0`

But when I `import cassandra` from jupiter notebook I got :
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import cassandra
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cassandra'

I'm using python 3, os: windows 10
So, why it's not able to access cassandra as on cmd?

Comment: for example, becaue Jupyter may use another Python setup, or something like...

Comment: @AlexOtt, So how I can install it for jupter ? !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute !pip install cassandra-driver on Jupiter notebook
then import cassadra
goes well !