# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flair'

Tags: python, nlp, flair

I have installed flair library via the following command

```
!pip install flair
```

but when i tries to import it, it will generate error like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flair'"

**Code:**

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.embeddings import TransformerDocumentEmbeddings
```

Comment: Did you run `pip list | grep flair` and check if its installed?

Comment: yes it is installed, i can see via pip list --> flair                              0.8.0.post1

Comment: you might have more than one python/pip installed on your machine

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working and https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Comment: after install i need to restart kernel, that resolved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install via the following command make sure you use --user option otherwise you will get a permission error in windows 10.

```
!pip install --user flair
```

after install flair you have to restart kernel in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

For the case if anyone find this thread and had the same problem: flair is installed, but python says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flair.data'; 'flair' is not a package`

In my case the problem was a noob error: the name of my script has the same name like the package: `flair.py`. After renaming my script to `flair_ner.py`everything works fine.