# Getting in Jupyter notebook: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'podman'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, podman

I am using Jupyter notebook to try out the Podman python package (https://pypi.org/project/podman/3.2.1/).
However, even after intalling the podman package, I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'podman'`.

Here is the screenshot for my jyupter notebook:

[image]

I am using Python 3.9 and pip 21.2.4. What am I missing here (I am relatively new to Python).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190436/1581658 ?

Comment: Thanks @SamBob for sharing it. That worked `%pip install podman`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this answer based on @SamBob's comment and corresponding SO post.

> In IPython (jupyter) 7.3 and later, there is a magic %pip and %conda command that will install into the current kernel (rather than into the instance of Python that launched the notebook).

So, `%pip install podman` worked for me.