# Jupyter notebook opening a console to fill sudo password

Tags: python, linux, bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've opened a jupyter notebook through my terminal on ubuntu, and am trying to run part of the notebook that has a `sudo -S pip install -e .` command.
It will hang on prompting for a password due to the sudo.
I'm not sure how to circumvent this, I've tried the following:

1. `%qtconsole` opens a console which seems tied to the notebook, however it freezes up during the sudo, when I try to sudo within the console it also doesn't let me press enter on typing the password.
2. Defining the command, username, and password. And then using `command_with_password = f'echo "{password}" | sudo -S -u {username} {command}'`. This gives `pip not found` which is odd since just a bit earlier in the notebook it runs some `!pip install`s just fine

I have anaconda ready to go too, someone suggested there might be a solution there but I did not find it.

Any help is appreciated, I'd rather want a solution similar to [1] with some kind of console that makes it easy to catch any prompts in the future or some method of elevating the notebook to not require passwords, but I'm desperate to try anything.

Comment: Would it make sense to run your notebook in a python virtual environment, then you wouldn't need root privileges to pip install something?

Comment: Actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working looks like what you want.