Pip adding a path entry that works for python but not jupyter
I have a library, I am installing it for development purposes using the command
$ pip install -e .

The library structure is this:
.
└── package-name/
    ├── package_name/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module1.py
    │   └── module2.py
    ├── setup.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── README.md

The pip command installs the package and appends this entry to the path:
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

[..., '/home/user_name/package-name/package_name']

When I import the package in my environment's python. I can import it fine. When I try to import it in jupyter, I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name'"
When I reinstall the library from the jupyter kernel. Same result.
However when I run:
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user_name/package-name')

I am able to import the package just fine.
So, I guess my question is, why is this happening?

Why can Python find the package at that path, but Jupyter cannot?
Can I tell Pip to add a different entry to the path?
How can I ensure that my users don't encounter this problem when installing this early-stage library?
Would changing the name of the top-level directory to match the src dir name have an impact?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

As to the first bullet point, the kernel environment is very particular and has to be connected specifically to what you want. Have you tried running %pip install -e . in your running Jupyter Notebook placed relative the right place, or adjust the path in the install command?

Yeah I have already tried running pip install from inside the notebook, that was unsucessful

You need to add the contents of your setup.py to the question. There is not enough information to help, currently. The installation would not add /home/user_name/package-name/package_name to the sys.path, so something else is doing that. Editable installations link your code in site-packages, they do not add the source directory directly to sys.path.

'Unsuccessful' does not adequately describe how it didn't work. Was it a path issue? Can you use other packages that you didn't make and does it work? That may provide you with a way to troubleshoot further.

Are you in a virtual environment? Are you running python -m jupyter notebook (instead of just jupyter notebook)?

try to check the directory the notebook is working on, try import os  os.getcwd() and if directory doesn't contain either copy the file or edit the path uri.

This is a standard error, and I struggled with it a lot - In Python, only the imported modules and variables are added to the memory, depending on how the code is written. Since Python is interpreted, it sequentially executes code line-by-line within the interpreter’s environment, loading imported objects into memory only as required.
Why can Python find the package at that path, but Jupyter cannot?
When you run pip install, it automatically runs in your Python environment, which has been predefined (automatically your base/system env if you do not have environments created and activated). In contrast, the Jupyter server is potentially running and using a different environment where the paths are not configured for the model. It has its own 'conda' enabled package manager system.
Can I tell Pip to add a different entry to the path?
Yes, but this is not advised, as it can lead to inconsistencies across installations. The real solution is to ensure you're installing in the correct environment.
You can also use pyenv and wrap conda around it to avoid activating conda every time. Pyenv will manage all packages and make them universally available.
Would changing the name of the top-level directory impact this?
Yes, for new files,  you create (not package manager-managed files), and the directory structure affects how you structure your imports. If you change from:
src/import1/function1
to:
abc/import1/function1
You'd need to update your imports from:
from src.import1 import function1
to:
from abc.import1 import function1
How can I ensure users don't encounter this problem?
Activate the Conda environment that Jupyter uses before installing packages.
Install your package in that environment.
# First activate the right environment
conda activate your_jupyter_env

# Then install your package
pip install -e .


As @Wayne said on comment in a jupyter you can use below command to install pip package
%pip install -e .

instead of regular pip install in general python environment.

Instructions to Install jupyter lab on Debian.

Create python virtual environment and activate it.

python3 -m venv env 
source env/bin/activate

You may need to install python3-venv package. So run
$ sudo apt install python3-venv

After all we have a ready environment to work with.
Now we can install our especial module inside this environment.
We install our new python package i.e. package-name inside venv virtual environment with
python3 -m pip install -e . or similar command like
pip install -e .
$ python3 -m pip install -e .



Install jupyter lab inside it.

python3 -m pip install jupyterlab

Check it with pip freeze

And run with

jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0

Now Jupyter web interface will fire on IP address on port 8888.
So underlying environment venv currently have package-nam module as we can see with pip freeze here in jupyter lab also we have it.

Related answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190436/7508077


Potential Causes
This sounds like you have an issue with the script not being installed into your environment. This can happen due to a number of reasons:

You are not using the correct pip. This can be diagnosed using which pip, which will show you the path of the pip binary you are running.
The jupyter kernel is running in a different environment. This is more likely, as you may have accidentally installed jupyter globally (very easy to do).

Steps to try and fix:
These steps are solutions to the potential causes I have listed, however, without additional information it is hard to give more detailed troubleshooting.

Create a fresh conda environment. When working with notebooks I highly recommend using conda rather than venv or virtualenv. Install conda if you don't have it already: https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge (the best flavour of conda)

$ conda create -n myenv python=3.11 jupyter pip # or change python version to whatever you need

$ conda activate myenv


Double check that the pip you are using is inside the conda env

$ which pip
# /<path_to_conda_env>/bin/pip


Install package

$ pip install -e .


Launch jupyter

Remarks
This solution is similar to the solution given by EsmaeelE. It is hard to diagnose this issue which getting additional info. If possible can you give us:

which pip
which pip -a
which jupyter
Contents of setup.py
Python version
Does pip install . work?


"When working with notebooks I highly recommend using conda": curious: why?

Conda is better generally for data science as it installs the environment in a central location and can be easily used across projects. venvs are best suited for library or application development, as they typically live inside your project. This is more of my opinion rather than hard answers. From my experience, I have had more issues with notebooks and venvs rather than conda, not too sure why...

#2 is the culprit. When you give Python a script to execute, the directory containing that script is added to the search path. When the "script" is specified by -c, it's treated as being contained in the current working directory. Whatever Python process is started by jupyter almost certainly has a different working directory.
