# can't import package pandas, statsmodels and matplotlib on Jupyter for anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, statsmodels

I failed to import package pandas statsmodels and matplotlib in Jupyter in Anaconda 2,

```
import pandas
import statsmodels
import matplotlib as mpl
```

for example the error information for **import pandas** like this

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import pandas
>
> /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py
>   in ()
>        29                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
>        30                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
>   ---> 31                       "extensions first.".format(module))
>        32 
>        33 from datetime import datetime
>
> ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import
>   pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py
>   build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

but I can import numpy, scipy,sklearn correctly

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
```

In addition, if I use Spyder or ipython on Anaconda, it works for all the 6 packages mentioned above. I used the Mac OS 10.10.5, Python 2.7.12 Anaconda 2 (x86_64). The question is similar to the question mentioned in the following link, but the answer seems not work for my problem (I have deleted the python 2.7 installed on the Mac by default).

[Import pandas on jupyter ipython notebook fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253338/import-pandas-on-jupyter-ipython-notebook-fails)

Comment: You shouldnt have done this (I have deleted the python 2.7 installed on the Mac by default).

Comment: I can't import them as well before I remove the default python.

Comment: Your mac need the default python for the OS!!! You may have destroyed your OS. USE brew!!!!!!!!

Comment: Which part of the OS can't destroyed? Do I need to reinstall the python 2.7 with brew?

Comment: This is a developers forum, not tech support. I would get on mac forums - and ask the question..

Comment: Are you in a particular environment inside anaconda ?

Comment: @Rubens_Z  I have fixed the problem by simply upgrade it into the anaconda 3.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall and reinstall pandas and try again. Also if there are useless files in your directory delete them.